# How to create a Dojo Tree with Root from Constructor

Tags: tree, dojo, root

I need to create the single root data for a dijit.Tree in the browser with a function.

This works when I create the root object inline. But it breaks if I create the same object with a function.

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

The code can be found here:
[Testcase](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/attachment/ticket/12594/TreeConstructor.html)

Answer (score -1):

Dojo does not like objects that are created with the "new" language keyword.